# Trying to update Asus BIOS

Tags: uefi, hardware

My UX31 zenbook is experiencing some weird shutdown behavior when the battery drops below 50% and the internet seems to agree that updating the BIOS is a good step forward since there were issue with the kernel before.

I downloaded both the correct BIOS file and the windows 7 utility tool and now need to boot FreeDOS to run, however, I've tried every method out there and they all fail (or so I think):

1. Using unetbootin's FreeDOS 1.0 image I get to an error saying it couldn't run drivers then I get to a command line on disk A:. I assumed a dead end.
2. Using unetbootin but with the FreeDOS 1.1 version image downloaded directly: get an error of "bad or missing command interpreter". I looked online and the solutions didn't work either.

So, is there an alternative to FreeDOS or to installing a BIOS that I could use?

Comment: **To reviewers:** This is not about another operating system, but assisting an **Ubuntu user** facing a usability or hardware issue, that seems to be solvable. Don't close, just because of *Jehovah*. You (or somebody you know) eventually might end up in a situation where you don't know how to ask the question that solves your problem some day too.

Comment: From the answer below: "This is not related to Ubuntu, you should have asked the question on another Stack Exchange site"

Comment: Yes, I got that. What was the purpose of rehashing what was already explained.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** [Read the manual](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=369&m=UX31A&os=30&hashedid=DNit7f9PxhWaH1Wi) ([page A-12](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX21A/E_eManual_UX21A_UX31A_VER7124.pdf#p64)).

This product, like others, has an integrated update functionality. Put the update on a USB stick, select "EZ Flash" or "Easy Flash" from the UEFI boot menu and do the update from within this program.

---

This is not releated to Ubuntu, you should have asked the question on another Stack Exchange site. However:

> 1. Using unetbootin's FreeDOS 1.0 image I get to an error saying it couldn't run drivers then I get to a command line on disk A:. I assumed a dead end.

No, I think that is the correct behaviour. *Depending on what error messages you got* (some might not be releated to the task you are trying to accomplish). You then need to run the update utility and point it to the update it should apply. The difficult part may be to find out in which drive or directory the tool and update reside.

Also there is the possibility that there doesn't exist a DOS-based update tool, or the tool is not compatible to FreeDOS (and earlier versions of MS DOS) and has to be run from a Win9x boot disk (I remember facing such a problem with a 2011 model ProBook and some service technician tools).

Comment: ok yeah this is getting me somewhere. People talked about using FreeDOS for my laptop which is why I was trying to do it this way And I posted directly on ubuntu because I tried the "Easy Flash" and it also fails (it was obviously my first option). It just doesn't ever find the update. I will try that again as the FreeDOS option is frustrating me.

Comment: You should also try another USB stick or what you have, because there might be issues with the filesystem type (should be FAT32), partitioning (there shouldn't be a partition table) or just plain electrical issues (that somehow just appear in this system state), if you haven't already. Also there might be an issue of understanding how the interface works and how to navigate (it looked like a TUI without mouse support in the manual). The scheme for naming filesystems and devices in UEFI is `fs1` [see](http://www.hardwareasylum.com/images/asus_p9x79/bios_ezflash.jpg), browsing is similar to DOS.

Comment: Yup, been doing that for the past couple of hours. Will continue until fixing the issue then post it since I can't find the same issue solved anywhere else (other than with the methods that I failed at)